# Copying a rigged object and having it use the same armature

Tags: rigging, blender-internal-render-engine

*Is it possible to copy a fully rigged object and connect it to the same armature with the same rig weights?,  i have been having issues with this*

Comment: Yes this is possible, please be more specific in what the problem is.

Comment: I want to copy a fully rigged object.
what happens at the moment is that the armature is also copied. 
i think this is a problem, i prefer those two to have the same armature. Either I would like a way to merge the 2 armatures, or attach it to another armature without having to re apply the weights.

Comment: I dont really understand the problem, just dont select the armature when duplicating.

Comment: hmm, on mine the armature is automatically copied with it even when i select only the object.

Comment: Here is a small illustration.
i do only select the object.

[link](http://adriel.site/abc.png)

Comment: Please write exactly, step-by-step, HOW you duplicate the object. Write out the buttons and operations or record a video.

Comment: I select the specific object i want copied, then i press ctrl-c and ctrl-v. then the armature copies with it.

Comment: Please use Shift D to duplicate objects. Ctrl-C + Ctrl-V copies the entire object group with all data.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> is the way to copy a specific object.